# Dukt Video plugin oAuth issue with development environment

Tags: plugin-duktvideos, plugin-duktoauth

I'm wondering if anyone has come across this issue I have with the Dukt Video plugin and oAuth using it in a development environment using craft.dev?

Google oAuth only excepts top level domains for the re-direct url so the .dev url gets flagged as incorrect so I am unable to add the the redirect url to Google.

I've also encountered a problem on Vimeo where is throws a cURL error #60 after trying to connect.

And trying to use oAuth with Facebook or Twitter throws the following error:

> cURL Error # 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I need to test the plugin in a development environment so does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Have you tried contacting [DUKT support](https://dukt.net/support)? _Edit: Sorry, I just saw [your other question regarding this plugin](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/issues-with-duct-oauth-plugin). Seems the developer is not being responsive ATM._

Comment: I have no problems using a craft.dev domain for Google OAuth callbacks